# Adding an arrow on an histogram using ggplot2

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I'm experiencing some problem when trying to add an arrow to a stacked histogram using ggplot2.

Firstly I created the dataframe using

```
set.seed(1234)

df <- data.frame(
  sex=factor(rep(c("F", "M"), each=200)),
  weight=round(c(rnorm(200, mean=55, sd=5), rnorm(200, mean=65, sd=5)))
)
```

Then I ran the following code in order to get the plot with an arrow pointing to a specific value

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=weight)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=sex, color=sex), position="stack", alpha=0.5, binwidth=5) +
  stat_bin(aes(y=..count.. + 2 , label=..count..), drop="TRUE", geom="text", binwidth=5)

p + geom_segment(aes(x=52, xend=52, y=30, yend = 0), colour="darkblue", size=1, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")))
```

but I get the following warning message: **ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead**

Then I modified the previous code as:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=weight, ymax=..count..)) +     geom_histogram(aes(fill=sex, color=sex), position="stack", alpha=0.5, binwidth=5) + stat_bin(aes(y=..count.. + 2 , label=..count..), drop="TRUE", geom="text", binwidth=5)

p + geom_segment(aes(x=52, xend=52, y=30, yend = 0), colour="darkblue", size=1, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")))
```

but in this case I get the following error message: **Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'count' not found**

Where am I wrong? 
Thanks in advance for all the help you could provide me with

Comment: Your first attempt seems to work fine and the warning is harmless. Is there something wrong with the way the first plot looks?

Comment: As @eipi10 said: you can ignore the warning. Or exchange `y=..count..` by `ymax=..count..`. In addition, `x=52, xend=52, y=30, yend = 0` doesn't necessarily need to be wrapped in aes...